# How to remove more items from combobox?

Tags: c#, string, combobox

I am trying to remove more items from a combobox but the application is only removing one item at a time.

The `combobox` has a list of email addresses.  I want to remove empty items `("")`, and those that don't have `@` inside of text.

Code below only removes one item at a time.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cmbTo.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string st = cmbTo.Items[i].ToString();
        if (st == "" || st.IndexOf("@") == -1)
        {               
            cmbTo.Items.RemoveAt(i);                    
        }
    }
```

How can I rewrite this?

Comment: `and @ (that don't have).` don't have What...??

Comment: how about looking at something simple like this `cmbTo.Items.AddRange(all.Where(x => x != string.Empty).ToArray());`

Comment: some.name@gmail.com have @ .... some.mailgmail.com don't have @

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you already have?

Comment: Be careful when removing items in a collection that you are iterating. The `for` is checking the `Count` property, which is varying because the `RemoveAt`

Comment: if you have some.mail@gmail.com, some.mail2gmail.com, some.mail3gmail.com it will remove only some.mail2gmail.com but it have to also some.mail3gmail.com ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Think about what happens to the `i` variable when you remove an item

...

When you RemoveAt an item, the item is removed, and every subsequent item moves up one index. Your loop then hits the bottom, where it goes back to the top, increments `i`, and moves on.

Result? You just skipped an item. If this is the last item in the list, then the loop exists.

Instead, manually decrement `i` to offset your removal, so that everything works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmbTo.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string st = cmbTo.Items[i].ToString();
    if (st == "" || st.IndexOf("@") == -1)
    {               
        cmbTo.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because the moment you remove an item from the collection, the Count() decreases and the for loop exits before going through all the list of items.

You need to first create a list of elements to remove (put them in a temp list) and then iterate through the newly created list calling `cmbTo.Items.Remove(currentElement);`

Comment: Unfortunately, [ComboBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) doesn't have a setter, so you won't be able to assign that temporary list back to the combo box.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I am not saying that he should set the Items to the temp list but rather loop through the temp list and call `cmbTo.Remove(currentItemInTempList)`.

Comment: OK, but in this case, how would you represent "an item that doesn't contain @"? What would the `currentItemInTempList` be in that case?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an item from a combobox, the indices of the following items change and your item count will change. Could that account for the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the removal in the opposite direction (i.e. from the end to the front), and you won't need to worry about adjusting `i`<sup>1</sup> when the item is removed:

```
var items = cmbTo.Items;
int i = items.Count;
while (i > 0) {
    --i;
    string st = items[i].ToString();
    if (st == "" || st.IndexOf("@") < 0)
        items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Which you currently don't do, so some items that should potentially be removed  are skipped, which causes your problem.